# Reverse the CSS animation using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

Here is a code that animates a progress bar using the CSS keyframe. Now the problem is what if we want to reverse the animation at some point in the middle of the CSS animation?

I mean at second 4 while CSS animation is working I want to suddenly pause it and reverse the animation and animate the bar to the very beginning.

Here is what I have tried...

I think it's possible and I'm missing something cause the reverse animation doesn't affect the bar at all and is kind of wired!

**Note:** Any kind of solution (like TweenMax) is accepted ...

```js
//first of all pause the animation
pauseUsingCSS();
console.log("pauseUsingCSS executed!");

//after 2 seconds play it
setTimeout(function(){   
   playUsingCSS();
}, 2000)

//Two seconds later reverse the animation to where it started using JQuery
setTimeout(function(){       
   reverseUsingJquery()
}, 4000)


function reverseUsingJquery(){
    // Here Is Where The Problem Exist...
    pauseUsingCSS(); // pause the animation first
    $('#progress-bar').animate({width: 0, marginLeft: 0}, {duration: 1000});
    console.log("reverseUsingJquery initiated!");
    
}

function pauseUsingCSS(){
   document.getElementById("progress-bar").classList.add("paused");  
}

function playUsingCSS(){
   document.getElementById("progress-bar").classList.add("played");
   console.log("playUsingCSS executed!");
}
```

```css
#progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  border: 0vh solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 0vw;
  height: 9.436435124508519vh;
  margin: 62.909567496723468vh 0vw 0vh  11.2119791666666659491vw;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red, red 2.80299479166666659491vw, orangered 2.80299479166666659491vw, orangered 5.60598958333333297455vw);
  border-radius: 18vh;
  animation: roll 10s linear forwards;
  box-shadow: inset 0vw 7.8636959370904332vh 1.40149739583333318982vw rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0vw 0.7863695937090432vh 0vw rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0vw -3.9318479685452166vh 0.42044921875vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0vw 2.3591087811271296vh 0.280299479166666681018vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  left: -0.70074869791666659491vw;
  top: -3.9vh;
}

#progress-bar:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 28.0299479166666681018vw;
  height: 15.7273918741808664vh;
  border: 0.140149739583333340509vw solid rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.7);
  background: rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.7);
  border-radius: 18vh;
  content: "";  
  left: -0.70074869791666659491vw;
  top: -3.9vh;
  z-index: -1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes roll {
  0% {
    width: 1vw;
  }
  100% {
    width: 26.6284505208333318982vw;
  }
}


.paused {
   -webkit-animation-play-state: paused !important; 
}

.played {
   -webkit-animation-play-state: running !important; 
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  
<div id="progress-bar"></div>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script src="script.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what i have done below is create a keyframe called `roll-back` based off the current width of the element and insert it into the head of the site. Then on reverse i add an inline animation style of `roll-back` which does the trick. This was as well you can control the flow of the reverse animation as you can customise the timings etc.

I also created a function to allow you to reset the dynamic changes so that it can be resumed going forwards easily.

```js
//first of all pause the animation
pauseUsingCSS();
//console.log("pauseUsingCSS executed!");

//after 2 seconds play it
setTimeout(function(){   
   playUsingCSS();
}, 2000)

//Two seconds later reverse the animation to where it started using JQuery
setTimeout(function(){       
   reverseUsingJquery()
}, 4000)


function reverseUsingJquery(){
    // Here Is Where The Problem Exist...
    pauseUsingCSS(); // pause the animation first
    let progress = $('#progress-bar');
    
    var css = `
        @-webkit-keyframes roll-back {
          0% {
            width: ${progress.width()}px;
          }
          100% {
            width: 1vw;
          }
        }
    `,
    head = document.head,
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.id = 'rollback';
    head.appendChild(style);
    
    progress.css('animation', 'roll-back 10s linear forwards');

    style.type = 'text/css';
    if (style.styleSheet){
      style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {
      style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }
    
    playUsingCSS();
    //console.log("reverseUsingJquery initiated!");
}

function resetBarStyles(){
    $('#progress-bar').attr('style', '');
    $('#rollback').remove();
}

function pauseUsingCSS(){
   document.getElementById("progress-bar").classList.add("paused");  
}

function playUsingCSS(){
   document.getElementById("progress-bar").classList.add("played");
   //console.log("playUsingCSS executed!");
}
```

```css
#progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  border: 0vh solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 0vw;
  height: 9.436435124508519vh;
  margin: 62.909567496723468vh 0vw 0vh  11.2119791666666659491vw;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red, red 2.80299479166666659491vw, orangered 2.80299479166666659491vw, orangered 5.60598958333333297455vw);
  border-radius: 18vh;
  animation: roll 10s linear forwards;
  box-shadow: inset 0vw 7.8636959370904332vh 1.40149739583333318982vw rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0vw 0.7863695937090432vh 0vw rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0vw -3.9318479685452166vh 0.42044921875vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0vw 2.3591087811271296vh 0.280299479166666681018vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  left: -0.70074869791666659491vw;
  top: -3.9vh;
}

#progress-bar:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 28.0299479166666681018vw;
  height: 15.7273918741808664vh;
  border: 0.140149739583333340509vw solid rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.7);
  background: rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.7);
  border-radius: 18vh;
  content: "";  
  left: -0.70074869791666659491vw;
  top: -3.9vh;
  z-index: -1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes roll {
  0% {
    width: 1vw;
  }
  100% {
    width: 26.6284505208333318982vw;
  }
}


.paused {
   -webkit-animation-play-state: paused !important; 
}

.played {
   -webkit-animation-play-state: running !important; 
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  
<div id="progress-bar"></div>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script src="script.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS animation has an `animation-direction` property. Keeping that in mind you could try something like this:

```
function reverseUsingJquery(){
    $('#progress-bar').css("animation-direction", "reverse");
}
```

This would apply an inline style on that element, causing the animation to change direction from forward to reverse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... plus one... but this way we lose our keyframes and a jump occurs in the animation (try it)... besides we can not control the speed of reverse animation...